# Backup server with tar, encrypt and directly transfer the result, AFTER BUFFERING IT

Tags: ssh, backup, tar, openssl, buffer

So I've been investigative how to make full backups with `tar`, and I found that `tar` is a good tool if the backup is to be made once, and if the server has enough disk space to handle the output file.

I was able to play around the second condition [by dumping the output of the encrypted backup through SSH even with encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088632/tar-and-encrypt-with-openssl-and-dump-the-result-directly-to-an-ssh-server/30102493#30102493). Now this is fine, except that it's very slow, and makes my other server connection busy all the time.

I would like to improve that further, by making it possible to *buffer* my backup in the current server, and then transfer the buffered data after exceeding a specific size. Is this possible to achieve?

If you require any additional information, please ask.

Comment: Can you please post the command you're actually using?

Comment: Consider using something like fsarchiver instead.

Comment: @dr01 It's in the link.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I'll read about it later. It's on my task list now. Thanks for the suggestion.